# i can not find data/data/<package name>/databases folder in DDMS in eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse

*I go to the DDMS view in Eclipse while the program that accesses the DB is running. When I go to the data/data directory, I only see folder called "con". Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages or permission denied messages in logcat or console? BTW android keeps those folders private. You need to be rooted in order to access them

Comment: I am not getting this type of error